# Xamarin Failed to resolve assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm getting this error when I deploy to IOS. I'm working on windows connected to a Mac Book pro. The solution has 3 projects (Forms, Droid and Ios)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to resolve assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' App2.iOS

Comment: you need to check if you have a reference to a Droid dll in your iOS project

Comment: Checking it ....

Comment: Thanks @Jason, you were right. I was referencing a Droid Dll in my iOS project